# In DAML, how to find and replace an element in a List

Tags: daml

If I have a list of data [Item], what is the best way to locate and change an element in it.

```
aList : [Item]
searchName : Text
newPrice : Decimal


- I can find the element using 
let a : Optional Int = findIndex (\a -> a.name == searchName) aList

-but this doesn't change the value of the List
let (aList !! fromSome a).price = newPrice

data Item = Item 
  with
    name : Text
    price : Decimal
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in DAML are *immutable* - that means once you have created a list there is no way to update any value within it. However, there are lots of helper functions that can be used to create a new list a lot like the old one, but with some changes. As an example:

```
let newList = map (\a -> if a.name == searchName then a{price = newPrice} else a) aList
```

The `map` function takes each element of the list and applies the given function. The function we are passing changes the `price` for those with the right name, and returns all the others unchanged. Note that unlike your version, this changes all items with `searchName` rather than just the first - I'm assuming that's fine (but if not, look to functions like `partition` to divide the list first).

Comment: Thanks Neil, it works perfectly. Just curious if it can be done by Map. Didn't find any function in Map that can return a new map back...

Comment: If you are working on the data type `Map` then there is the function `fmap` which works on any `Functor` - and `Map` is a `Functor`. Just replace `map` above with `fmap`.